# Usage of a different kind of functions in one Java Class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am following this tutorial to create my first Spring Hibernate JSF app, and in this tutorial http://marco-ng.blogspot.com/2014/02/primefaces-jsf2-spring-security-spring.html?showComment=1440293840519#c5483896447188701172 the developer used a UserDAO and CustomerDAO which are one for getting login name and the other to manager customers. For my sample, I'm using one class User merging the two used functions (User will login, and then he will manager totality of Users).

My Question is, can I simply merge those two DAO in one UserDAO :

User DAO :

```
package spring.dao;

import spring.model.User;


public interface UserDAO {
    public User getUser(String login);
}
```

Custommer DAO :

```
package spring.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import spring.dao.CustomerDAO.ComponentScan;
import spring.model.Customer;

import java.util.List;




@Repository
public class CustomerDAO {

    public @interface ComponentScan {

    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(customer);
    }

    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(customer);
    }

    public Customer getCustomerById(int id) {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Customer where id=?").setParameter(0, id).list();
        return (Customer)list.get(0);
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Customer").list();
        return list;
    }

}
```

The goal of all this is about using Management functions as long as Login from same class. And as I'm following a tuto to learn, I can't know the exceptions or things that are impossible to do before asking about them.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DAO can't be merged because login needs an interface which is has no superclass but an interface. This means both DAO remains but both inherit data from model UserDAO.

Answer (score 0):

**NO** both `DAO` should remain sepparated.

You can (and should for what you explain) create a single service for all the management, in this service `ManagementBS` for example you must inject `DAO`'s with `@Autowired` annotation.

What you can do is a `BasicDAO` using reflection for basic operation like `save`, `getById`, `delete`... shared between all classes.

Comment: Seems you didn't understood my purpose, for my case, User logins AND manages Users from DB

Comment: Maybe you mean using model User gathering both functions , and then a loginDAO importing USer, and a UserDAO also importing user, but each for a different kind of functions ?

Comment: I did a User class, and two DAO, UserLoginDAO and UserDAO, both imports User, is that correct ?

Comment: don't use answers to add information, edit your question. You should post both `DAO`'s and `User` class, to get an answer.